# Jenkins - DSL / pipeline password Parameter problem

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

We have a been using a particular password parameter in our Jenkins
Job DSL and pipelines (passwordParameterDefinition). But after
upgrading to Jenkins 2.249.x we can no longer use that parameter due to
an unresolved issue  [LINK1](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360055603872-Unable-to-set-a-default-value-for-passwords-in-declarative-pipeline-using-Job-DSL-plugin) [LINK2](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64539)

All of our jobs are created using jbd-dsl and groovy files and
for reasons I will not get into now, I am updating a few of these
jobs to use the nonStoredPasswordParam with the mask-passwords plugin.

THE CODE
Here is an example of a pipeline definition that is using this parameter.

```
pipelineJob('job/path/deployment/aws-parameter-store-job') {
  parameters {
      choiceParam('ACTION', ['Create', 'Update', 'Delete', 'Get'])
      stringParam('AppName', '', 'Enter the application')
      stringParam('AppEnv', '', 'Enter environment') 
      stringParam('Name', '', 'Enter Parameter Name')
      choiceParam('Account', ['sandbox','nonProd'], "Choose an AWS Account.")
      nonStoredPasswordParam('PASSWORD', 'Enter the password')
      // NOTE: the parameter below is being replaced 
      // by the nonStoredPasswordParam above ^^
      // passwordParameterDefinition {
      //   name('SECRET')
      //   defaultValue(null)
      //   description('SECRET')
      // }
    }
  environmentVariables {
      env('REGION', 'us-west-1')
  } 
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
            remote {
                url('git@my.gitserver.com:Automation/aws-parameter-store.git')
                credentials('creds')
            } 
            branch('development')
            extensions {
            cleanBeforeCheckout()
            }
         }
      }
      scriptPath("jenkinsfile")
    }
  }
}
```

And Here is a jenkinsfile for the pipeline that uses this parameter for in this job:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('encrypt') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', credentialsId: "awskey-${env.Account}"]]) {
                sh script: "set +x; aws --region us-east-1 ssm put-parameter --name '/deployment/${Account}/${AppName}/${AppEnv}/${Name}' --type 'SecureString' --value '${PASSWORD}'"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I have also tried --value '${params.PASSWORD} and --value '${env.PASSWORD}

THE RESULT
The job runs without error, but the parameter being passed is not the PASSWORD, but null.

There are no good examples of using the nonStoredPasswordParam in a pipeline. I have been working on this for DAYS.

TL;DR Why is my nonStorePasswordParam returning null?